# how to submit the slider value on mouse leave instead of submitting all values until mouse leave

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, slider

i have a input field and slider which has range between 1 to 100.
since i have toggle switches and drop downs i keep onChange events for each field instead of submit button including for slider also.

but i am facing an issue if i try to change slider from 1 to 50 all values upto 50 are submitting using **onChange** and i tried to use **onSlideEnd** but it showing old value (ex: showing 1 when selecting 50 from 1 and showing 50 when selecting 20 from 50).

i want it like while changing from 1 to 50 only 50 should send to back end from **handleSubmit**

i tried this code but not working please help

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Slider } from "primereact/slider";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
//some imports

const Config = () => {

  const [factorvalue, setFactorValue] = useState(1);
  const [isSliderDragging, setIsSliderDragging] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchConfig();
  }, []);
  
  const fetchConfig = async () => {
    try {
      // this is used to get config value from backend to set in front
      const response = await Service.getMaliciousFactorConfig();
      if (response) {
        const maliciousFactorValue = response[0].maliciousFactor || 1;
        setFactorValue(maliciousFactorValue);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderChange = (event) => {
    try{
      const newValue = parseInt(event.value, 10);
      setFactorValue(newValue);
      handleSubmit(newValue);
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderDragEnd = (event) => {
    setIsSliderDragging(false);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
      setFactorValue(newValue);
      handleSubmit(newValue);
    } else {
      setFactorValue("");
    }
  };

    const handleSubmit = async(value) => {
      try{
         if (value >= 1 && value <= 100) {
            setValidationError("");
            await ConfigService.setConfig(value);
         }
      }catch(error){
         console.log(error);
      }
    };

  return (
          {//demo code}
          <div className="displayFlex">
            <label htmlFor="factor">Factor:</label>
             <div>
               <InputText id="factor" value={factorvalue} onChange={handleInputChange} className="w-full" />
               <Slider value={factorvalue} onChange={handleSliderChange} onSlideEnd={handleSliderDragEnd} className="w-full" min={1} max={100} />
             </div>
          </div>
          {//some code}
  );
};

export default Config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking in right direction. Follow these steps to get it working (Assuming that you want to submit when `onSlideEnd` fires)

1. onSlider change, update the `fractionValue`, however don't call `handleSubmit`.
2. Call `handleSubmit` in `onSlideEnd`

```
<Slider value={factorvalue} onChange={handleSliderChange} onSlideEnd={()=> handleSubmit(factorvalue)} className="w-full" min={1} max={100} />
```

Comment: new value not reflecting immediately for example if i change from 1 to 50 it submitting 1 and changed from 50 to 60 submitting 50

Comment: That is because of async state updates. Instead try using useRef to update the value immediately

Comment: Thanks bro Mayank Kumar Chaudari i tried with useRef its working

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this and worked for me

```
import React, { useEffect, useState,useRef} from 'react';
import { Slider } from "primereact/slider";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";
//some imports

const Config = () => {

  const [factorvalue, setFactorValue] = useState(1);
  const factorValueRef = useRef(1);
  const [isSliderDragging, setIsSliderDragging] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchConfig();
  }, []);
  
  const fetchConfig = async () => {
    try {
      // this is used to get config value from backend to set in front
      const response = await Service.getMaliciousFactorConfig();
      if (response) {
        const maliciousFactorValue = response[0].maliciousFactor || 1;
        setFactorValue(maliciousFactorValue);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderChange = (event) => {
    try{
      const newValue = parseInt(event.value, 10);
      setFactorValue(newValue);
      factorValueRef.current = newMaliciousFactor;
    }catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const handleSliderDragEnd = (event) => {
    setIsSliderDragging(false);
    handleSubmit(factorValueRef.current);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const newValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(newValue)) {
      setFactorValue(newValue);
      handleSubmit(newValue);
    } else {
      setFactorValue("");
    }
  };

    const handleSubmit = async(value) => {
      try{
         if (value >= 1 && value <= 100) {
            setValidationError("");
            await ConfigService.setConfig(value);
         }
      }catch(error){
         console.log(error);
      }
    };

  return (
          {//demo code}
          <div className="displayFlex">
            <label htmlFor="factor">Factor:</label>
             <div>
               <InputText id="factor" value={factorvalue} onChange={handleInputChange} className="w-full" />
               <Slider value={factorvalue} onChange={handleSliderChange} onSlideEnd={handleSliderDragEnd} className="w-full" min={1} max={100} />
             </div>
          </div>
          {//some code}
  );
};

export default Config;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Debouncing looks like the right solution for you. [Read more](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/)

A react-hook is available [here](https://usehooks.com/usedebounce).

Install the hook: `npm i @uidotdev/usehooks`

How to use the hook:

```js
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(0);
const debouncedValue = useDebounce(sliderValue, 500);
useEffect(()=>submit(debouncedValue),[debouncedValue])
```

This will wait until sliderValue hasn't changed 0.5 seconds and then call submit with the value.